# Why do I have no WiFi on a MacBook Air 14,2?

Tags: wireless, 12.10, macbook-air

Just installed Quantal on my MBA. Wireless worked fine until I ran the first software-update and now it cant find the wireless driver. Wired works fine but I dont have root privileges on network and cant get software sources to open because of the security policy.

(I want to check if the Broadcom driver is selected.) Has anyone else experienced this problem, and if so, any idea on how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Same problem here. Original 12.10 worked fine, but after update wireless network interface is missing on MacBook Air 4,2.  After some digging and trying things out, I found that by going to "Software Source" and disabling the Broadcom additional driver and rebooting, my wi-if came back on.

Comment: That worked. Some issues with a package that had french characters in it breaking access to Software sources stop me from testing it for a while.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling Broadcom proprietary driver BCM43224 brought back wifi for me as well, Macbook Air 11 from August 2012 / 8GB / i7 CPU. Ubuntu 12.10